# A matrix with trace $\leq n$ is conjugate to a matrix with all entries $0,1,-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a matrix in $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$, let $a_{ij}$ denote the element in the $i$th row and $j$th column. Suppose $|tr(A)|\leq n$. Is it true that $A$ is conjugate to a matrix $B$ such that $|b_{ij}| \leq 1$ for all $i,j= 1, \ldots, n$?

Or what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for a matrix in $SL(n, \mathbb Z)$ to be conjugate to a matrix with all entries equal to $0$, $1$ or $-1$? It is obvious that not all matrices are of this form, for example $[5, 19; 1, 4]$  is in $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$ but can't be a matrix satisfying the property since trace is preserved under conjugation. I have found some families of matrices that satisfy it but can't come up with a criterion for this question.

Also any references on the subject would be appreciated.

Comment: For more on integer conjugacy classes in $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ see [Multidimensional Gauss reduction](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.0830v3.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the source, I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "conjugate" you mean "conjugate within $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb Z)$", this is not true. Consider the matrix

$$
\pmatrix{1&x\\0&1}\in\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)
$$

with $x\in\mathbb Z$ and with trace $2\le2$. We have

$$
\pmatrix{d&-b\\-c&a}\pmatrix{1&x\\0&1}\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}=\pmatrix{1+cdx&d^2x\\-c^2x&1-cdx}\;.
$$

For $|x|\gt1$, the condition can only be fulfilled if $c=d=0$, contradicting $ad-bc=1$.

Comment: Ok, I upvoted because that answers my first question. Do you know anything about the second? Maybe some geometrical criterion, such the matrix coming from the action of a diffeomorphism on the integral homology of a  manifold?

Comment: @Z.L.: I don't, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you think that question applies for MO?

Comment: @Z.L.: I'm not the best person to ask that; I don't spend much time on MO. I suspect that it would help if you could motivate why you think that such a criterion should exist.

Comment: I don't really suspect it should exist. I came up with this question by finding some families of matrices that did satisfy the property, and since it is a question that makes sense and I couldn't answer it, I posted it. Also, I am working on something unrelated at the moment so I'll rethink it in a few days and wait if someone knows something about the second question (or its difficulty)

Comment: @Z.L. Definitely it would help to know why matrices with entries $0,1,-1$ are interesting here. Without motivation it appears a bit random, e.g., we also could ask the same question for alternating sign matrices, or for matrices with entries only prime numbers.

Comment: As I said in other comment, I suspect that all matrices coming from the action on homology of (maybe periodic) automorphisms of manifolds satisfy that they are conjugate to matrices with only 0,1,-1. I asked to see if someone knew a characterization or something related. But I agree that you could ask the same question about other kind of matrices. For example, you can ask pretty much anything (without context) about finite groups and someone will answer. Mathematics should be self-explanatory. I don't know why telling you the reason for posing that question to myself would help to solve it.